# Equivalent of SED for MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, sed

I need to do the equivalent of a `sed` against a field in a mysql database, which the field data is in the form of xml.

In essence, I need to find `{sourcevalue}` below and replace it with `{scrubbedvalue}` in the example below. We cannot do direct matches on `{sourcevalue}` as it is unknown but the rest can be referenced.

Is there a simple way to do this with mysql out of the box? If not, is there a way to match via a regex to get the starting position and length of the match, and do the replace that way?

**Example Input:**

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    ...
    <entry key="foo" value="{sourcevalue}"/>
    ...
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

**Example Output:**

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    ...
    <entry key="foo" value="{scrubbedvalue}"/>
    ...
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleansing of data is best done *before* inserting.

If the string is in a column by itself, then a simple `UPDATE` does the trick.

If you are using MariaDB, see `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

If it is buried in a string, you really ought to use some application language to fix the code.

Comment: if the end cleaning doesn't need to uniquely identity the original location then a `sed` against the db dump would be easy enough. In my case there are several locations like the above that need unique "scrubbedvalue"s left behind for further manipulation by DevOps team. I like the comment about MariaDB, but we haven't migrated yet.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Mysql does not provide a simple "RegExp find and replace" function.

But there are several other options to solve the issue at hand:

**Option #1**

Normalize your data schema, by adding a new database table, e.g. "Attributes", with the "key" and "value" columns, and place your data into it, instead of keeping it inside the XML "blob".

This way you will be able to use a regular SQL syntax to query and update your attributes, and also properly index them as and if necessary.

**Option #2**

If #1 is not a viable option for you (for whatever reason),
you can try to use the new (Mysql 5.7+) [XML functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html), like that:

```sql
SELECT @xml:='<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="a" value="a"/>
    <entry key="foo" value="{sourcevalue}"/>
    <entry key="z" value="z"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>';

SELECT UpdateXML(
@xml,
'//entry[@key="foo"]/@value',
'value="{scrubbedvalue}"'
);
```

**Option #3**

If #2 does not work for you either (e.g. you are running an older version of Mysql), you can try to use raw string manipulation functions, to achieve the same result, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT @key:='foo';

SELECT 
REPLACE(
@xml,
SUBSTRING(
 @xml,
 @s:=LOCATE('"',@xml,LOCATE(CONCAT('key="',@key,'"'),@xml)+LENGTH(@key)+6)+1,
 LOCATE('"',@xml,@s+LENGTH(@key)+6)-@s),
"{scrubbedvalue}"
);
```

plus a [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) filter (to only update records which match)

```
WHERE @xml REGEXP 'key="foo"';
```

But you will have to take extra care if your XML chunks are not normalized and can be formatted differently (i.e. use different amount of whitespace, entity references e.t.c.).

Comment: If you can update your `Option 3` to take care of the white space issue, I'll accept your answer. I posted my work around I did yesterday, which isn't pretty, but takes the white space into account.

Comment: @VenomFangs, actually it is already "whitespace-proof" to some extent,
i.e. you can add any number of whitespace before and after the "key" and "value" attributes, or even insert some line-breaks, and it will still work, as it looks for the next "quoted" value, after the "key" (and does not just compute a position relative to it).

Comment: I'll review/test within the next couple of days. If all aligns, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For documentation purposes, I did the following yesterday, while waiting for answers.

This isn't pretty and can probably be reworked into something cleaner, but if all else fails, it should work for others.

I in essence get the left side of the value, right side of the value, then do a concatenate with the new value and update that to the db.

```
UPDATE mytable SET attributes = 
        CONCAT(
                -- length of 'value="' is 7. Want 7-1 == 6
                SUBSTRING(attributes, 1, LOCATE('value="', attributes, POSITION('foo' in attributes))+6), -- Left of value
                '%%SCRUBBED_VALUE%%', -- Scrubbed value.
                -- length of 'value="' is 7. Want 7 for next " reference.
                SUBSTRING(attributes, LOCATE('"', attributes, LOCATE('value="', attributes, POSITION('foo' in attributes))+7), LENGTH(attributes) - LOCATE('"', attributes, LOCATE('value="', attributes, POSITION('foo' in attributes))+7) + 1) -- Right of Value
        )
WHERE name = 'SomeUniqueIdentifier';
```